# Java, applet: How to block the activation of paint() before init() finishes it's work

Tags: java, methods, applet

I found out that the method `paint()` gets called some time (it can't happen immediately, can it?) after the activation of `init()`, not after it finishes. I have a few objects that get created in `init()` and drawn in the `paint()` method. But the drawing starts before the objects get initialized. This causes exceptions, that are handled automatically. But it also causes the objects not to get drawn after the the first activation of `paint()`- they need to be redrawn in order to show up.

I was able to block the `paint()` method's work with an infinite cycle, placed int the beginning of the method, that doesn't stop until `init()` finishes it's work (I guess `init()` and `paint()` run in separate threads). But an employed Java programmer told me that this isn't an elegant solution- I should try to do something different (the guy didn't tell me what to do, he is not working with applets and I guess, he has never encountered this problem, that's why I'm asking here).

How can I make sure that the `paint()` method doesn't activate before `init()` finishes working, and how can I make it in an elegant way (what ever that's supposed to mean in this case...)?

EDIT:

I am using Dr. Java- for some reason, it runs the applet differently on two different computers: a really old laptop (7-years-old) that runs with Win XP and a 2-years-old desktop PC that runs with Win 7. I have made the mistake not to test with a browser...

The problem doesn't occur when testing with Dr. Java on the desktop. And the problem doesn't occur when running the applet on a browser. It only occurs with the editor installed on the laptop. I guess the problem is in the code editor running on the "old tech", not in the code.

Comment: What's causing the `paint`?  I'd think Java itself would try not to call it til `init` is done, particularly considering Swing is not thread-safe (and i'm not sure about AWT, but most native objects aren't thread safe either, so...).  You have another thread triggering updates?  If so, tell it to wait...or, even better, don't even start the thread til the very end of `init`.

Comment: *"really old laptop (7-years-old) that runs with Win XP"*  Perhaps more relevant is what JRE does it run?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.  Init and paint are being called, as you suspected, by two different threads.

The most elegant solutions I think off of is

1. Check for nulls in the paint method
2. Use EventQueue.invokeLater in the init method and place the initialisation code within it, calling repaint when you're done

Answer (score 0):

```
public void init() {
   // do my initing...
   inited = true;
   repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
   if (!inited) {
      return;
   }

   // do my painting...
}
```

Comment: Uh... No. That's similar to my algorithm.

Comment: @AlekZanDer You said you put an infinite loop at the start of your paint method that only exited when init() finished.  That's pretty different.

Comment: But it still blocks the work of paint() until init() finishes.

Comment: @AlekZanDer: Isn't that *exactly what you asked for*?

Comment: It doesn't look more elegant than my way.

Comment: Aside from the lack of busy-waiting, you mean?  This doesn't draw, it doesn't loop.  It just returns.  It just ignores `paint` calls til `init` is done.  That's quite unlike an "infinite cycle", and doesn't tie up the EDT as a loop would.