# Java NullPointerException in call to paint()

Tags: java

My program is throwing a NullPointerException error upon trying to call the paint method of a ship.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ship extends Polygon implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
final static Point[] shape = new Point[4];
final static Point START_POSITION = new Point(400, 300);
private int windowX;
private int windowY;
Point pull;

public Ship(int maxX, int maxY) {
    super(shape, START_POSITION, 0);

    windowX = maxX;
    windowY = maxY;

    shipInit();
    init(shape);
    Point[] pointArray = getPoints();
    pull = new Point(0, 0);

}

public void shipInit() {
    shape[0] = new Point(0, 0);
    shape[1] = new Point(30, 10);
    shape[2] = new Point(0, 20);
    shape[3] = new Point(10, 10);   


}


public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    brush.setColor(Color.white);

    Point[] points = getPoints();

    if (position.x > windowX) {
        position.x -= windowX;
    } else if (position.x < 0) {
        position.x += windowX;
    } else if (position.y > windowY) {
        position.y -= windowY;
    } else if (position.y < 0) {
        position.x += windowY;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        int x1;
        int y1;
        int x2;
        int y2;
        if (i == points.length - 1) {
            x1 = (int) points[i].x;
            y1 = (int) points[i].y;
            x2 = (int) points[0].x;
            y2 = (int) points[0].y;
        } else {
            x1 = (int) points[i].x;
            y1 = (int) points[i].y;
            x2 = (int) points[i + 1].x;
            y2 = (int) points[i + 1].y;
        }

        brush.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

}


public void move() {
    position.x += 2;
    position.y += 5;
    // position.y += 1;
}


public void accelerate(double acceleration) {
    pull.x += (acceleration * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation)));
    pull.y += (acceleration * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation)));
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyPressed = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyPressed == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        System.out.println("Hi");
    if (keyPressed == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        accelerate(5);
        position.x += pull.x;
        position.y += pull.y;
    }
    if (keyPressed == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        rotation += 5;
    }
    if (keyPressed == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        rotation -= 5;
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And the class the calls the paint

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Asteroids extends Game {
private static int frameWidth = 800;
private static int frameHeight = 600;
Ship player;

public Asteroids() {
    super("Asteroids!", frameWidth, frameHeight);
    init();
}


public void init() {
    player = new Ship(800, 600);
    this.addKeyListener(player);
    repaint();
}


public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    brush.setColor(Color.black);
    brush.fillRect(0, 0, width,height);

    brush.setColor(Color.white);
    String hi = "hi";
    brush.drawString(hi, 299, 399);

    player.paint(brush);
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Asteroids();

}

}
```

The error says that the error is thrown when calling player.paint(brush). Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: What does `Game` extend from?  How is `paint` called?

Answer (score 0):

I have never coded in this before, but a quick trip to the universe of google explained to me that paint() and init() runs on 2 different threads.
That said, your paint() method gets called BEFORE the init() method.

A quick way to fix this would be to have a boolean that gets set inside init()
Like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Asteroids extends Game {
private static int frameWidth = 800;
private static int frameHeight = 600;
Ship player;

private boolean hasInitialized; // Initialization check

public Asteroids() {
    super("Asteroids!", frameWidth, frameHeight);
    init();
}


public void init() {
    player = new Ship(800, 600);
    this.addKeyListener(player);
    hasInitialized = true; // We set the boolean to true to indicate that we have initialized.
    repaint();
}


public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    if (!hasInitialized) return; // Nope, not ready yet, we'll stop here.

    brush.setColor(Color.black);
    brush.fillRect(0, 0, width,height);

    brush.setColor(Color.white);
    String hi = "hi";
    brush.drawString(hi, 299, 399);

    player.paint(brush);
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Asteroids();

}

}
```

I'm not 100% certain this will fix it, considering you already have init() inside the constructor.
But it's worth a try!

Source: [Java, applet: How to block the activation of paint() before init() finishes it's work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710524/java-applet-how-to-block-the-activation-of-paint-before-init-finishes-its)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that is at all possible, but I don't know what `Game` extends from.  You `init` method is been called from your constructor, which, technically means it can't be placed on a container to be painted, unless your painting it your self from within `Game` some how...If `Game` extends from any type of `Swing` or `AWT` component, you're also breaking the paint chain...there simply isn't enough information available to either help you with your question or know if this answer is actually correct or not...

Comment: Agreed, we need more information to be able to help you with this issue. But I can't really see any other way this could be happening.

Comment: Having made some additions to other parts of the program it has stopped throwing that error. For the record, Game extends Canvas.